# Carrierwave asset_path becomes undefined method when used in rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Rails 5.1.1, 
ruby 2.2.5p319, 
Carrierwave 1.1.0

Trying to refactor out a view piece that gets reused all over the app into a helper and I'm hitting a wall. There are two carrierwave uploaders on the Issue model: Image and Imageback. I'm passing variables to the method in order to determine which column I'm trying to hit (passed as `graphic` in the code below)

Helper method (in `application_helper.rb`):

```
def issue_image_display(issue, graphic, size, sizeinpx, lodge = nil)
  if graphic
    if graphic == "imageback"
      link_to image_tag(issue.imageback_url(size)),
      imageback_url(:full), rel: :lazybox
    else
      link_to image_tag(issue.image_url(size)),
      image_url(:full), rel: :lazybox
    end
  else
    image_tag(
      "missing_flap.jpg",
      alt: "No Flap Image for #{issue.combined}",
      style: "width: #{sizeinpx}px"
      )
  end
end
```

This is being invoked by the following:

```
<ul class="issue-list" id="issues">
  <div class="page">
    <%# cache issue do %>
      <%= render partial: "issues/issue_small",
              collection: @issues,
              as: :issue,
              wishlist: false,
              locals: {
                size: :list,
                sizeinpx: '200'
              } %>
    <%# end %>
  </div>
</ul>
```

and that partial that is iterated over, calling the actual helper method:

```
<li class="issue-container">
  <article class="issue">
    <%= issue_image_display(issue, issue.image, size, sizeinpx) %>
    <p class="lodge-name">
      <%= link_to issue.combined, lodge_issue_path(issue.lodge, issue) %>
      <span><%= issue.first_issue.stamp("1969") if issue.first_issue %> | (OA BBv6: <%= issue.oa_bb_combined %>)</span>
    </p>
    <% if :wishlist == true -%>
    <p class="add-to-wishlist">
      <%= link_to 'Add to Wishlist', wishlist_items_path(issue_id: issue.id), method: :post, class: "button button-small" %>
    </p>
    <% end -%>
  </article>
</li>
```

The error is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error at /issues
undefined method `asset_path' for #<ImageUploader::Uploader70194310458580:0x007faec5409400>
```

Comment: In which line of the code you are getting that error?

Comment: It calls it as Line 16 of the file that invokes the partial, which when including the other stuff I trimmed is: `<%= render partial: "issues/issue_small",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are two failures above. ActionView was masking them so I kept pulling it higher until I got a meaningful line number.

```
 if graphic
    if graphic == "imageback"
      link_to image_tag(issue.imageback_url(size)),
      imageback_url(:full), rel: :lazybox
    else
      link_to image_tag(issue.image_url(size)),
      image_url(:full), rel: :lazybox
    end
  else
```

was missing the `issue` call before `image_url`, and so it was calling the carrierwave method on nothing.

The second issue was the `if graphic` check. Turns out that's always true in the way it is written. To get past that, it needed to become `if !graphic.blank?`. That was secondary to the actual error, but documenting it for anyone running into weirdness like this in the future.